# How to parse a SOAP response in iOS (objective C)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, soap

How to validate the `username` and `password` from a website having no `SSL certificate`? I want to `parse the response`. I dont know how to implement the `SOAPEngine class` described in the github site.
Github link:https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine

Answer (score 1):

For Validate Try ->

```
#import <SOAPEngine64/SOAPEngine.h>

SOAPEngine *soap = [[SOAPEngine alloc] init];
soap.userAgent = @"SOAPEngine";

// authorization
soap.authorizationMethod = SOAP_AUTH_BASIC; // basic auth
soap.username = @"my-username";
soap.password = @"my-password";
```

or

[iOS Basic SOAP Authentication process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873956/ios-basic-soap-authentication-process/36657101#36657101)

and Parser 
Check [How to work with SOAP web service and XML parsing in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867328/how-to-work-with-soap-web-service-and-xml-parsing-in-swift/36655348#36655348)

However this in Swift but the logic is the same.